# Template data is replaced

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I generate 2 templates dynamically using Blaze.renderWithData.
Data is different each time.

```
contactForm.each(function(index) {
  const parent = $(selector).get(index);
  const data = {email: parent.dataset.email}; // here data are different
  Blaze.renderWithData(Template.contact, data, parent);
});
```

When I log data in the templates' onCreated function, the data is different. But in onRendered, the first template data is in fact replaced by the second template data.

Why is that ?

```
Template.contact.onCreated(function() {
  console.log('onCreated', this.data.email);
});

Template.contact.onRendered(function() {
  console.log('OnRendered', this.data.email);
});
```

Results:

```
onCreated 1
onCreated 2
onCreated 3
OnRendered 3
OnRendered 3
OnRendered 3
```

Comment: Does the same behavior occur when passing the data from the HTML template using `{{ > contact .... }}`?

Comment: It was an error on my part: https://forums.meteor.com/t/template-data-is-replaced/49678

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, it was an error on my part:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/template-data-is-replaced/49678